# What is the differences btw appearance features and semantic features?

Tags: computer-vision

In computer vision fields, What is the differences between **appearance features** and **semantic features** ?

Answer (score 0):

Those are generally vague terms that depend on the context and the author, and can be used interchangeably. But usually, I think that the term "appearance features" describes the geometric/photometric attributes of a primitive, for example its texture, its surface normal or curvature, etc. These properties can usually be captured in a more or less reliable manner by some local statistics (*e.g.* traditional SIFT-like descriptors). They tend to be mostly local.

Semantic features, on the other hand, tend to usually be more "high-level", in the sense that they can't be inferred in a trivial manner from local statistics. They describe the meaning of an entity with respect to other entities in the scene, so they are usually tied to the segmentation of the scene into objects that don't only make sense mathematically, but are recognizable as physical objects. For example, a semantic feature for a set of pixels in an image would be something like "trees with red leaves". According to Wikipedia, *In ontology engineering, the term semantics refers to the meaning of concepts, properties, and relationships that formally represent real-world entities*. I think this is coherent with the explanation given above.